# Save custom keyboard shortcuts in Gnome

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, gnome-shell, dconf

On my Debian system I've customized my Gnome (Shell) keyboard shortcuts, via System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts.

Where do I find the file with these settings so that I can copy the file onto a flash drive for backup and then use it to replace the keyboard shortcuts on other Gnome systems?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/26056/where-are-gnome-keyboard-shortcuts-stored

Comment: Related: [How to set custom keyboard shortcuts from terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1017580/1333)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Gnome 3 uses [`DCONF`](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-overview.html) to store the preferences in a single binary file: `~/.config/dconf/user`.
As per the Gnome docs, it is recommended to save only the settings that you need and restore them with either [`dconf`](https://developer.gnome.org/dconf/unstable/dconf-tool.html) or [`gsettings`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/unstable/gsettings-tool.html). However, `gsettings` is only able to restore the value(s) for one single key at a time (plus, the value must be quoted) and that makes it a bit awkward for this kind of task. Which leaves us with `dconf`.
So, in this particular case, save the current settings for `gnome-shell` keyboard shortcuts<sup>1</sup>:

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/shell/keybindings/ > bkp
```

Here's a `bkp` sample:

```
[/]
toggle-message-tray=['<Super>m']
open-application-menu=['<Super>F1']
toggle-application-view=['<Control>F1']
focus-active-notification=['<Super>n']
toggle-recording=['<Control><Shift><Alt>r']
```

Load the settings on another system:

```
dconf load /org/gnome/shell/keybindings/ < bkp
```

---

1: WM and Media Keys shortcuts belong to different schemas:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/
/org/gnome/mutter/keybindings/
/org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/
```

Note that `dconf` *only dumps non-default values* so if you run e.g.

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/
```

and don't get any output that means there's no custom WM shortcut defined.

---

As a side note, `dconf-editor` is a tool that helps visualizing `dconf` settings structure, i.e. `schema [:path] key value`, the type and the default values of any key etc.

---

For the record, saving the preferences with `gsettings`:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.shell.keybindings > bkp
```

`bkp` sample:

```
org.gnome.shell.keybindings focus-active-notification ['<Super>n']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings open-application-menu ['<Super>F1']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-application-view ['<Super>a']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-message-tray ['<Super>m']
org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-recording ['<Control><Shift><Alt>r']
```

Now loading the preferences (as I said, for each line in the backup file you need a separate command and don't forget to quote the values):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings focus-active-notification "['<Super>n']"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings open-application-menu "['<Super>F1']"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-application-view "['<Super>a']"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-message-tray "['<Super>m']"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings toggle-recording "['<Control><Shift><Alt>r']"
```

Comment: `dconf dump /org/gnome/shell/keybindings/ > bkp` does not work on Centos 7.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to edit my comment and got blocked by stack exchange. Doing a `dconf dump /` can help show what keys are available though. On Centos I had the terminal bound to `Ctrl+Alt+T` and it shows up in `org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0`. Dumping `org/gnome` seems like a good way to backup most things on Centos 7.

Comment: For anyone using custom keyboard shortcuts for non-defaults actions: These are stored in `/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/` under `custom-keybindings` (as an example: I've defined some shortcuts to place the mouse pointer at the center of each of my screens).

Comment: No `/org/gnome/shell/keybindings/` on Fedora 28.

Comment: @don_crissti `dconf` only saves settings that are modified, and it saves them at different locations.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik - yes and no. Yes, the `user-db` (database) only saves user settings that have been modified but the question here is about _custom shortcuts_ (i.e. _shortcuts defined by the user_). What is the point of your 1st comment then ? And no, it doesn't save them in different locations, all modified settings are saved in a single binary file: `~/.config/dconf/user`

Comment: `user-db` contains a lot more than just keyboard shortcuts. For locations I meant schemas. And the point is that - there is no defined namespace for shortcuts, so it is impossible to write a script that will dump and restore 100% of custom shortcuts and won't dump and destroy everything else.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik - there are mainly four schemas that deal with global shortcuts, as I wrote in another comment on one of your questions: shortcuts for `gnome-shell`, `wm`, `mutter` and `media-keys` (I even edited the post above to include them _even though this question is about gnome-shell shortcuts_) so it is very possible and easy to write a script that will dump those and restore them when needed. I'm not sure why you say this would _"destroy everything else"_... Sure, there are other shortcuts that are application specific but we're not discussing about those here.

Comment: @anatolytechtonik I'm using GNOME 3.30.2 on Debian 10. The command have changed to `dconf dump /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/`.

Comment: I have created a script that was loosely inspired by this answer and currently considers the two dconf namespaces that contain my shortcuts, but it should be fairly easy to modify if someone misses something: https://gist.github.com/peterrus/e59a96688a4d49ee3d9302c0d3ff5fdd

Answer (score 9):

### Save custom keyboard shortcuts

You can save/backup/export custom shortcuts/keybindings using just [`dconf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dconf.1.html) and `sed`

#### Export

```bash
dconf dump / | sed -n '/\[org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys/,/^$/p' > custom-shortcuts.conf # Export
```

The difference with the usual answer is that this will hold on the file the path to the dconf settings, making it easier to import, just `dconf load / < file`.

#### Import

```bash
dconf load / < custom-shortcuts.conf # Import
```

#### Notes

- Based on [Ciro's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/746262/349837) (also [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1093110/349837))
- Only for the added custom shortcuts
- Note that `dconf` only dumps non-default values
- To backup, you may want to use `custom-shortcuts-$(date -I).conf`
- Test if it works by [resetting to defaults](https://askubuntu.com/a/315226/349837) before the import

  ```
  gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Search for keybindings like so:

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep keybindings
```

Set a keybinding like so:

```
org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings close "['<Alt>F5']"
```

Note that keyboard tweaks overlapping bindings will break the latter. For instance, `switch-applications-backward ['<Alt><Shift>Tab']` will be overridden by layout switch `"Left Alt" + "Left Shift"`, so that `['<Left Alt><Left Shift>Tab']` will not work, where as `['<Left Alt><Right Shift>Tab']` will.

Setting keybinding for layout switch like so `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Shift>Alt', '<Super>space']"` or `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['<Alt>Shift', '<Super>space']"` does not make it work.

Gnome v3.28.1

Answer (score 0):

### Scripted Solution

A script to backup keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu 20.04 that was developed from looking at above answers (Thank you everyone!)

It saves a series of `.conf` files and also generates a `restore.sh`. The resulting folder can be copied to a new computer and used to setup shortcuts.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"

export DCONF_DUMP="$SCRIPT_DIR/dconf-dump"
echo "Backing up keyboard shortcuts to $DCONF_DUMP ..."
mkdir -p $DCONF_DUMP

export RESTORE_SCRIPT="$DCONF_DUMP/restore.sh"
echo '#!/bin/bash
# Auto-generated script to restore shortcuts
set -e
SCRIPT_DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" &> /dev/null && pwd )"
' > $RESTORE_SCRIPT

# Build this list by looking at output from: gsettings list-recursively | grep keybindings
for ELEM in desktop/wm/keybindings mutter/keybindings mutter/wayland/keybindings settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys
do
    export OUTPUT_FILE="$DCONF_DUMP/$ELEM.conf"
    export ORIGIN="/org/gnome/$ELEM/"
    
    export PARENT=$(dirname $OUTPUT_FILE)
    mkdir -p $PARENT
    dconf dump $ORIGIN > "$OUTPUT_FILE"
    
    export INPUT_FILE="$ELEM.conf"
    echo "dconf load $ORIGIN < \$SCRIPT_DIR/$INPUT_FILE" >> $RESTORE_SCRIPT
done
```