# How can I copy mouse sensitivity between computers?

Tags: gnome3, mouse

I would really prefer both my computers (with the same mouse, Razer DeathAdder) to have the same exact mouse sensitivity, unfortunately I tweaked one via the control panel and I can not get it to default back. I am always working in a Debian, Gnome3-based, desktop environment. (Currently LinuxMint 17.1).

Where are mouse setting stored and how can I back them up and reapply them to new hosts?

Comment: [Save custom keyboard shortcuts in Gnome](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119432) - the same applies to your mouse settings, you just change the subpath: `dconf dump /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse/ >backup_file` etc...

Comment: Also, reset the keys on the other machine before loading the backup config: `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse/` then `dconf load /org/gnome/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse/ < backup_file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Save custom mouse setup

You can save/backup/export custom shortcuts/keybindings using just [`dconf`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/dconf.1.html) and `sed`

#### Export

```bsh
dconf dump / | sed -n '/\[org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouses/,/^$/p' > custom-mouse-setup.conf # Export
```

The difference with the usual answer is that this will hold on the file the path to the dconf settings, making easier to import, just `dconf load / < file`.

#### Import

```bsh
dconf load / < custom-mouse-setup.conf # Import
```

#### Notes

- Note that `dconf` only dumps non-default values
- To backup yo migth want to use `custom-mouse-setup-$(date -I).conf`
- Test it's working by [resetting to defaults](https://askubuntu.com/a/315226/349837) before the import

  ```
  gsettings reset-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse
  ```

Comment: Thanks, and for my notes, I found the cinnamon mouse settings under org/cinnamon/settings-daemon/peripherals/mouse