# A way to export/import gpaste settings

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

TLDR: how can I export/import settings for `gpaste`?

I am using `gpaste` on Ubuntu 18.04 with Gnome. And as always migrating from previous Ubuntu installation not as easy as I would want to because because I am always doing clean install and then migrating my apps and some settings. Now installing gpaste with script is easy, what is not easy (for me) is to setup it.
Is it possible to export/import settings? I was not able to find where settings are stored so I presume gpaste uses some default data storage provided by Ubuntu (Gnome?) but still not sure what to do and to google it.

Comment: What's the output of `gsettings list-recursively | grep --ignore-case gpaste`?

Comment: @don_crissti, as experienced stack site user, what would you recommend to do with this question/answer: delete question, mark the answer as community wiki, or leave it as it is with my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @don_crissti suggested and as described in [Save custom keyboard shortcuts in Gnome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119432/save-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome) I was able to export/import gpaste settings with:

```
dconf dump /org/gnome/GPaste/ > gpaste.dconf.settings
dconf load /org/gnome/GPaste/ < gpaste.dconf.settings
```