# Which system files configure global keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

Obviously in many distros you can set global keyboard shortcuts via the GUI system settings. However, where are these stored?

I don't mean the keyboard config, but I mean keyboard shortcuts like super-a for applications or suoer-left-arrow to move windows. These cannot be set using xmodmap, but have to be set e.g. in X11 or gnome?

I'm particularly looking where ctrl-shift-e is set, but would like to understand the mechanism.or setting such global keyboard ahortcuts (that initiate "system functions"  like window moves).

I'm aware that this will differ between distros, and tips about Ubuntu 19.04 / X11 are particularly welcome. However I'm interested in general.

Comment: I'm assuming that wherever they are stored, it would possibly be tied to the particular window manager or desktop environment that you happen to be using. As there are a great variety of these, it would be helpful if you mentioned what you are currently using.

Comment: check this article https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134182/134202

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu, the following perl script shows system settings, including keybindings.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

@s = split /\n/, `gsettings list-schemas`;

foreach (@s) {
    system "gsettings list-recursively $_";    
};
```

Also see https://github.com/bjohas/Ubuntu-keyboard-map-like-OS-X.